# Finding a Suitable Radius to prove FTA using Rouche's Theorem

Tags: complex-analysis

I am tasked with trying to prove the FTA (Fundamental Theorem of Algebra) using Rouche's Theorem.  So I start with an arbitrary polynomial in complex variable with complex coefficients,
$$F(z)=a_nz^n+a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+...+a_1z+a_0=0$$

Which I can rewrite as a monic polynomial by dividing by $a_n$ and letting $c_k=\frac{a_k}{a_n}$ giving me the polynomial
$$F(z)=z^n+\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_kz^k=0$$
By writing it this way, i can let $f(z)=z^n$ and $g(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_kz^k$.  Now I need a path to contain all the roots, so I need to pick a radius $R$ that contains all the roots in $\mathbb{C}$.  So if I let the path be $|z|=R$, I need to find the $R$ such that
$$|f(z)|=|z^n|=R^n\ge\left|\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_kz^k\right|$$
By the Triangle Inequality, I know that
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}|c_kz^k|\ge\left|\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}c_kz^k\right| $$
So now I have
$$R^n\ge |c_{n-1}|R^{n-1}+...+|c_1|R+|c_0|$$
It's here I get stuck.  I suppose I could assume that there is some power of $R$ that is greater than all the coefficients $c_k$, so for example $|c_k|\le R^{m_k}$ but even doing this I'm having a hard time pinning down a suitable $R$.  I have thought about using the fact that $2^n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}$ and thus $2^n\gt\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}$...I feel like I've been staring at it too long and just can't pick a simple number to reflect these ideas and finish the proof. Once I pick my $R$, i can use Rouche's Theorem and it should be done.  but again, an appropriate R, i'm just not seeing it...

Comment: If $R \geq 1$, $R^k \leq R^{n-1}$ for $k \leq n-1$. So take that as given. Crudely estimate $R^k$ by $R^{n-1}$, for $k \leq n-1$. Now you need $R$ big enough that $R^n \geq R^{n-1} \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} |c_k|$.

Comment: So, really, with this, I can just assume that I need to find a radius $R$ that is bigger than the sum of the moduli of the coefficients.  If I assume then that  all $|c_k|<r$ for some real $r$, then the sum is less than $nr$  Is this suitable?

Comment: You also need $R>1$. @Lalaloopsy

Comment: Thank you.  I think this is all i need.  @Ian, if you would type that up as an answer, I would +1.  Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Let $F(z)=a_nz^n+\dots+a_0$ and $f(z)=a_nz^n$ and $g(z)=a_{n-1}z^{n-1}+\dots a_0$ such that $F(z)=f(z)+g(z)$.
Now consider $\frac{g(z)}{f(z)} = \frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}z^{-1}+\dots +\frac{a_0}{a_n}z^{-n}$.
It's easy to see that there exists an $R>0$ such that for all $|z|>0$, the absolute value of the fraction $\frac{g(z)}{f(z)}$ is strictly smaller than $1$. Since $|f(z)| \geq 1$ for sufficient large $|z|$, also $|g(z)|<1$.
Now we have $|f(z)|>|g(z)|$ on $C(0,R)$. As $f$ has $n$ roots within $B(0,R)$, $F$ should also have $n$ roots by Rouché's theorem.